# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ";" in C:\xampp\htdocs\native\admin\process_login.php on line 19

Tags: php

```php
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
        )
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Comment: You forgot an `)` in `if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and you also got an unwanted `)` after that. I'm voting to close this though, as it's a very generic programming question.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\native\admin\process_login.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\native\admin\process_login.php(22): clean('admin') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\native\admin\process_login.php on line 16

Comment: This code does not appear to have anything to do with WordPress. Is there a reason you posted the question here?

Answer (score 1):

You have added an extra `)`. You need to remove that.

Use this code

```
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
  if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $str = stripslashes($str);
  }
  return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Comment: Oh.. I have just updated my answer. Please check now.